# Input IO redirect file contents into a custom shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to accomplish this,

```
myscript.sh import -i < input.txt
```

`myscript.sh` is a custom script

`import -i` is some supported options in my script

`input.txt` is a input file for my script whose contents I want to read 
with myscript.sh(at least if I get the text 'input.txt' into the script will help)

I could see that `input.txt` doesn't come in as part of the sys args of the shell script because of the `<` before the `input.txt`.

Please suggest a way to get the input.txt file contents or the 'input.txt' text into myscript.sh

Most of the suggestion I came across using input file redirection seems to be with in-build shell commands.

Comment: The content of input.txt *is* available in `myscript.sh`. It is it's standard input. Now how to deal with it, depends on what you want to do with the input. For example, if you want to process it line by line, the command `read X` reads the next line of standard input an places it into the variable `X`.

Comment: I really do not understand your question? If you just execute `myscript.sh import -i input.txt` without the `<` then input.txt will be accessible as the first sys arg. Why wouldn't you want that?